# UITextField visibility false in appium test iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, appium

I have devoleped a simple iOS app and on test using Appium all  the UIControls staus is shown as visibility false. The below image is the screenshot of the test. I set accessibility label on storyboard

[image]

The code I wrote for a simple textfield is given below.

```
 self.txt_txt.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
 self.txt_txt.accessibilityElementsHidden=NO;
```

I have done  a little R&D on this and haven't found anything keep 'visibility ' true for UIControls.How to keep visibility true in the above case.If not in code are there any other scripts to run?. Any thoughts are welcome.

Comment: No matter whatever UIControls we are adding ,the visibility is false.But the QA team is pretty sure that it can be set to true .Have anyone face this issue..Please share some thoughts

Comment: Its a surprise that nobody have faced this issue .

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a bug when using iOS8, based on the information shown in the Appium bug database here:

https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/4131

Looking at the last comment to this bug, it seems that in iOS7 elements are correctly identified as "visible: true", but the same ones in iOS8 are not.

As far as I understand it, at the moment it's not yet clear if this is a bug in Appium or in iOS8.

Comment: Thanks man.I tried with an IOS 7.1 device, but still visibility was false....,Deployment target was also 7.1 ...Appium version is 1.3.4.Any way thanks

Comment: This is not a answer, it should be a comment!